# How to autocapitalize an input fileds globally using Angular formly

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I want to auto capitalize  all the letter in input fields while user is typing. Is it possible using

> formlyConfigProvider.setWrapper

Is there is any way to do same globally using angular formly?

Answer (score 0):

With Angular-formly, it is possible just by adding a watcher.listener to the field.

```
ctrl.fields = [{
    key: 'lastname',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
        label: 'Last name',
        placeholder: 'Ex: PETERSON'
    },
    watcher: {
        listener: function(field, newValue, oldValue, formScope, stopWatching) {
            console.log('watch lastname', arguments);
            formScope.model.lastname = formScope.model.lastname.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

well i am not good at formlyConfigProvider.setWrapper,but  i have a good directive to autocapitalise the inputting data

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .directive('capitalize', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        var capitalize = function(inputValue) {
          if (inputValue == undefined) inputValue = '';
          var capitalized = inputValue.toUpperCase();
          if (capitalized !== inputValue) {
            modelCtrl.$setViewValue(capitalized);
            modelCtrl.$render();
          }
          return capitalized;
        }
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(capitalize);
        capitalize(scope[attrs.ngModel]); // capitalize initial value
      }
    };
  });
```

simply add the directive to the input field,i know this was something shitty but the working is good